# How can I optimize my SQL Query (Multiple Rounds)

Tags: sql-server, c#

I'm try to round the sum of every month for the current und and last year. But with thousands of entries this query is slow. How can I optimize it? I want to use the results in a C# Application.

The Query:

```
SELECT  
(SELECT CAST(10001 AS varchar)) AS KdNr,  
(CAST(2014 AS varchar)) AS LastYear,  
(CAST(2015 AS varchar)) AS CurrentYear,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=1 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=1 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY1,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=2 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=2 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY2,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=3 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=3 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY3,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=4 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=4 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY4,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=5 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=5 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY5,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=6 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=6 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY6,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=7 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=7 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY7,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=8 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=8 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY8,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=9 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=9 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY9,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=10 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=10 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY10,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=11 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=11 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY11,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=12 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=12 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY12,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear) - (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=LastYear)),2)) AS LY,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=1 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=1 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY1,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=2 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=2 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY2,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=3 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=3 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY3,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=4 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=4 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY4,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=5 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=5 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY5,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=6 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=6 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY6,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=7 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=7 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY7,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=8 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=8 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY8,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=9 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=9 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY9,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=10 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=10 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY10,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=11 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=11 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY11,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=12 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=12 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY12,  
(ROUND(((SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear) -(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt),0) FROM FK_Auftrag WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (4) AND bStatus_storniert=0 AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=CurrentYear)),2)) AS CY
```

The Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "F1"."FK_Auftrag" (
    "SheetNr" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    "AuftragsNr" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    "AuftragsKennung" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "BelegKreis" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "KundenNr" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "LieferantenNr" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "ProjektNr" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "KundenMatchcode" VARCHAR(35) NULL,
    "VorgangNr" INTEGER NULL,
    "SammelRgNr" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "BestellNr" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "Bearbeiter" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "Kontierung_DebitorenNr" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Kontierung_Forderungskonto" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bKontierung_Ausland" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Kontierung_EG_ID_Nr" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "Konditionen_Zahlungsbedingung" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "Konditionen_Skonto_Text" VARCHAR(240) NULL,
    "Konditionen_Skonto_Text_Rechng" VARCHAR(240) NULL,
    "Konditionen_Ziel_Tage" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Konditionen_Skonto_Tage" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Konditionen_Skonto_Proz" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Konditionen_PreisgrpNr" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "Konditionen_Rabatt" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Konditionen_Rabatt_Proz" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Konditionen_Waehrung" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Konditionen_Zahlungsart" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Konditionen_Lieferart" VARCHAR(200) NULL,
    "bKonditionen_ist_brutto" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bKonditionen_keine_ust" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bKonditionen_rabatt_direkt" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bKonditionen_Monatsrechnung" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bKonditionen_Lieferstop" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Kostenstelle" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Kostentraeger" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Anschrift_Anrede" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Firma" VARCHAR(60) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Name" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Vorname" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Zusatz" VARCHAR(60) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Ansprech" VARCHAR(60) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Strasse" VARCHAR(35) NULL,
    "Anschrift_HausNr" VARCHAR(5) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Ort" VARCHAR(35) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Plz" VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Land" VARCHAR(35) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Tel1" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Tel2" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Fax" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "Anschrift_Email" VARCHAR(60) NULL,
    "Texte_Kopftext" VARCHAR(5000) NULL,
    "Texte_Fusstext" VARCHAR(2000) NULL,
    "Datum_erfassung" TIMESTAMP NULL,
    "Datum_zahlung" TIMESTAMP NULL,
    "Summen_netto_haupt" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Summen_brutto_haupt" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Summen_netto_neben" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Summen_brutto_neben" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Summen_ust_gesamt" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Summen_abschlag_netto" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Summen_abschlag_brutto" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Summen_abschlag_ust_schluessel" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Summen_abschlag_ust" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Summen_abschlag_forderung" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Summen_abschlag_erhalten" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "Summen_gesamt" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "bStatus_lagergebucht" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_gebucht" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_uebernommen" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_gedruckt" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_exportiert" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_geliefert" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_gemahnt" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_bezahlt" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_liefer_fakturiert" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_export_ascii" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_export_datev" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_abschlag" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_weitergefuehrt" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_erfassung_komplett" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_internet" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Verweis_weiter_aus_nr" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Verweis_weiter_in_nr" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Verweis_SchlussRgNr" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Verweis_GesamtRgNr" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Version" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Status_drucken" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Status_gedruckt" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "System_created" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP,
    "System_created_user" VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT USER,
    "System_updated" TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMP,
    "System_updated_user" VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT CURRENT USER,
    "bStatus_gemailt" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_frankiert" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Summen_roherloes" DOUBLE NULL,
    "Summen_roherloesEK" DOUBLE NULL,
    "Summen_roherloesVK" DOUBLE NULL,
    "bStatus_storniert" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStornoOrgGebucht" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lStornoOrgKennung" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lAboID" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lAboVorlageID" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "tsAboBegin" TIMESTAMP NULL,
    "tsAboEnde" TIMESTAMP NULL,
    "fAboAbgeschlossen" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lWiedervorlageID" INTEGER NULL,
    "Konditionen_Skonto_Tage2" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "Konditionen_Skonto_Proz2" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "szRMA" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "szLieferantSteuerNr" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "bKontierungUmkehr_13b" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lKontierungFrage_13b" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lFkNumID" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "tsLieferTermin" TIMESTAMP NULL,
    "szUserdefined1" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    "szUserdefined2" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    "szUserdefined3" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    "lAnschriftID" INTEGER NULL,
    "dftSummen_Selbstkosten" DOUBLE NULL,
    "bSelbstkostenKomplett" INTEGER NULL,
    "dftSummen_Gegeben" DOUBLE NULL,
    "bBarbeleg" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lKasseID" INTEGER NULL,
    "lBonNr" INTEGER NULL,
    "lZahlungsart" INTEGER NULL,
    "tsZahlung" TIMESTAMP NULL,
    "lKundengruppenID" INTEGER NULL,
    "lVertreterID" INTEGER NULL,
    "lBranchenID" INTEGER NULL,
    "szAgetoID" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    "lHerkunft" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "bStatus_Teilgezahlt" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lSammelRgnOrderUp" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "lAbschlagRgnOrderUp" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "tsServiceZeitpunkt" TIMESTAMP NULL,
    "szKundendienstler" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "bKV_verbindlich" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lAnschriftID_Service" INTEGER NULL,
    "f2007Ready" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lElectronicInvoiceStatus" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "szElectronicInvoiceFile" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    "szElectronicInvoiceGuid" VARCHAR(40) NULL,
    "dftSumme_GewinnNetto_NAR" DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT 0.0,
    "bBarKasse" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "szACCVersionInfo" VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    "lProvEmpfaengerID" INTEGER NULL,
    "lProvEmpfaengerVersionID" INTEGER NULL,
    "dftSummen_Gewicht" DOUBLE NULL,
    "szLeistungsDatum" VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    "szUserdefined4" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    "szUserdefined5" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    "szUserdefined6" VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    "bFixFaellig" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lTagVonMonat" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lTageVorlauf" INTEGER NULL DEFAULT 0,
    "lStatusPoststelle" INTEGER NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_FK_AUFTRAG" PRIMARY KEY ( "AuftragsKennung" ASC, "AuftragsNr" ASC )
) IN "system";
```

Some Sample Data:

```
    INSERT INTO "F1"."FK_Auftrag" ("SheetNr","AuftragsNr","AuftragsKennung","BelegKreis","KundenNr","LieferantenNr","ProjektNr","KundenMatchcode","VorgangNr","SammelRgNr","BestellNr","Bearbeiter","Kontierung_DebitorenNr","Kontierung_Forderungskonto","bKontierung_Ausland","Kontierung_EG_ID_Nr","Konditionen_Zahlungsbedingung","Konditionen_Skonto_Text","Konditionen_Skonto_Text_Rechng","Konditionen_Ziel_Tage","Konditionen_Skonto_Tage","Konditionen_Skonto_Proz","Konditionen_PreisgrpNr","Konditionen_Rabatt","Konditionen_Rabatt_Proz","Konditionen_Waehrung","Konditionen_Zahlungsart","Konditionen_Lieferart","bKonditionen_ist_brutto","bKonditionen_keine_ust","bKonditionen_rabatt_direkt","bKonditionen_Monatsrechnung","bKonditionen_Lieferstop","Kostenstelle","Kostentraeger","Anschrift_Anrede","Anschrift_Firma","Anschrift_Name","Anschrift_Vorname","Anschrift_Zusatz","Anschrift_Ansprech","Anschrift_Strasse","Anschrift_HausNr","Anschrift_Ort","Anschrift_Plz","Anschrift_Land","Anschrift_Tel1","Anschrift_Tel2","Anschrift_Fax","Anschrift_Email","Texte_Kopftext","Texte_Fusstext","Datum_erfassung","Datum_zahlung","Summen_netto_haupt","Summen_brutto_haupt","Summen_netto_neben","Summen_brutto_neben","Summen_ust_gesamt","Summen_abschlag_netto","Summen_abschlag_brutto","Summen_abschlag_ust_schluessel","Summen_abschlag_ust","Summen_abschlag_forderung","Summen_abschlag_erhalten","Summen_gesamt","bStatus_lagergebucht","bStatus_gebucht","bStatus_uebernommen","bStatus_gedruckt","bStatus_exportiert","bStatus_geliefert","bStatus_gemahnt","bStatus_bezahlt","bStatus_liefer_fakturiert","bStatus_export_ascii","bStatus_export_datev","bStatus_abschlag","bStatus_weitergefuehrt","bStatus_erfassung_komplett","bStatus_internet","Verweis_weiter_aus_nr","Verweis_weiter_in_nr","Verweis_SchlussRgNr","Verweis_GesamtRgNr","Version","Status_drucken","Status_gedruckt","System_created","System_created_user","System_updated","System_updated_user","bStatus_gemailt","bStatus_frankiert","Summen_roherloes","Summen_roherloesEK","Summen_roherloesVK","bStatus_storniert","bStornoOrgGebucht","lStornoOrgKennung","lAboID","lAboVorlageID","tsAboBegin","tsAboEnde","fAboAbgeschlossen","lWiedervorlageID","Konditionen_Skonto_Tage2","Konditionen_Skonto_Proz2","szRMA","szLieferantSteuerNr","bKontierungUmkehr_13b","lKontierungFrage_13b","lFkNumID","tsLieferTermin","szUserdefined1","szUserdefined2","szUserdefined3","lAnschriftID","dftSummen_Selbstkosten","bSelbstkostenKomplett","dftSummen_Gegeben","bBarbeleg","lKasseID","lBonNr","lZahlungsart","tsZahlung","lKundengruppenID","lVertreterID","lBranchenID","szAgetoID","lHerkunft","bStatus_Teilgezahlt","lSammelRgnOrderUp","lAbschlagRgnOrderUp","tsServiceZeitpunkt","szKundendienstler","bKV_verbindlich","lAnschriftID_Service","f2007Ready","lElectronicInvoiceStatus","szElectronicInvoiceFile","szElectronicInvoiceGuid","dftSumme_GewinnNetto_NAR","bBarKasse","szACCVersionInfo","lProvEmpfaengerID","lProvEmpfaengerVersionID","dftSummen_Gewicht","szLeistungsDatum","szUserdefined4","szUserdefined5","szUserdefined6","bFixFaellig","lTagVonMonat","lTageVorlauf","lStatusPoststelle") VALUES(1,'1001',0,0,'10001',NULL,NULL,'König Petra, Berlin',1,0,NULL,NULL,0,10001,0,NULL,'30 Tage netto','Zahlbar innerhalb von 30 Tagen ohne Abzug',NULL,30,0,0.0,1,0.0,0.0,978,0,NULL,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,'Frau','König Petra','König','Petra','Betriebswirtin (VWA)',NULL,'Freiburger Allee',NULL,'Berlin','12345',NULL,'030/123466',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Vielen Dank für Ihre Anfrage. Nachfolgend bieten wir Ihnen wie folgt an:',NULL,'2014-09-20 00:00:00.000',NULL,1998.4,2378.1,0.0,0.0,379.7,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,2378.1,0.0,2378.1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,'2014-10-01 19:04:08.000','U0','2014-10-01 19:29:07.421','U0',0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,0,1,0,0.0,NULL,NULL,0,0,0,'2014-09-20 00:00:00.000',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0.0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,0,0,0,'1900-04-08 00:00:00.000',NULL,0,NULL,0,0,NULL,NULL,988.0,0,NULL,0,0,0.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0,0,0);
INSERT INTO "F1"."FK_Auftrag" ("SheetNr","AuftragsNr","AuftragsKennung","BelegKreis","KundenNr","LieferantenNr","ProjektNr","KundenMatchcode","VorgangNr","SammelRgNr","BestellNr","Bearbeiter","Kontierung_DebitorenNr","Kontierung_Forderungskonto","bKontierung_Ausland","Kontierung_EG_ID_Nr","Konditionen_Zahlungsbedingung","Konditionen_Skonto_Text","Konditionen_Skonto_Text_Rechng","Konditionen_Ziel_Tage","Konditionen_Skonto_Tage","Konditionen_Skonto_Proz","Konditionen_PreisgrpNr","Konditionen_Rabatt","Konditionen_Rabatt_Proz","Konditionen_Waehrung","Konditionen_Zahlungsart","Konditionen_Lieferart","bKonditionen_ist_brutto","bKonditionen_keine_ust","bKonditionen_rabatt_direkt","bKonditionen_Monatsrechnung","bKonditionen_Lieferstop","Kostenstelle","Kostentraeger","Anschrift_Anrede","Anschrift_Firma","Anschrift_Name","Anschrift_Vorname","Anschrift_Zusatz","Anschrift_Ansprech","Anschrift_Strasse","Anschrift_HausNr","Anschrift_Ort","Anschrift_Plz","Anschrift_Land","Anschrift_Tel1","Anschrift_Tel2","Anschrift_Fax","Anschrift_Email","Texte_Kopftext","Texte_Fusstext","Datum_erfassung","Datum_zahlung","Summen_netto_haupt","Summen_brutto_haupt","Summen_netto_neben","Summen_brutto_neben","Summen_ust_gesamt","Summen_abschlag_netto","Summen_abschlag_brutto","Summen_abschlag_ust_schluessel","Summen_abschlag_ust","Summen_abschlag_forderung","Summen_abschlag_erhalten","Summen_gesamt","bStatus_lagergebucht","bStatus_gebucht","bStatus_uebernommen","bStatus_gedruckt","bStatus_exportiert","bStatus_geliefert","bStatus_gemahnt","bStatus_bezahlt","bStatus_liefer_fakturiert","bStatus_export_ascii","bStatus_export_datev","bStatus_abschlag","bStatus_weitergefuehrt","bStatus_erfassung_komplett","bStatus_internet","Verweis_weiter_aus_nr","Verweis_weiter_in_nr","Verweis_SchlussRgNr","Verweis_GesamtRgNr","Version","Status_drucken","Status_gedruckt","System_created","System_created_user","System_updated","System_updated_user","bStatus_gemailt","bStatus_frankiert","Summen_roherloes","Summen_roherloesEK","Summen_roherloesVK","bStatus_storniert","bStornoOrgGebucht","lStornoOrgKennung","lAboID","lAboVorlageID","tsAboBegin","tsAboEnde","fAboAbgeschlossen","lWiedervorlageID","Konditionen_Skonto_Tage2","Konditionen_Skonto_Proz2","szRMA","szLieferantSteuerNr","bKontierungUmkehr_13b","lKontierungFrage_13b","lFkNumID","tsLieferTermin","szUserdefined1","szUserdefined2","szUserdefined3","lAnschriftID","dftSummen_Selbstkosten","bSelbstkostenKomplett","dftSummen_Gegeben","bBarbeleg","lKasseID","lBonNr","lZahlungsart","tsZahlung","lKundengruppenID","lVertreterID","lBranchenID","szAgetoID","lHerkunft","bStatus_Teilgezahlt","lSammelRgnOrderUp","lAbschlagRgnOrderUp","tsServiceZeitpunkt","szKundendienstler","bKV_verbindlich","lAnschriftID_Service","f2007Ready","lElectronicInvoiceStatus","szElectronicInvoiceFile","szElectronicInvoiceGuid","dftSumme_GewinnNetto_NAR","bBarKasse","szACCVersionInfo","lProvEmpfaengerID","lProvEmpfaengerVersionID","dftSummen_Gewicht","szLeistungsDatum","szUserdefined4","szUserdefined5","szUserdefined6","bFixFaellig","lTagVonMonat","lTageVorlauf","lStatusPoststelle") VALUES(7,'4002',1,0,'10001',NULL,NULL,'König Petra, Berlin',1,0,NULL,'Herr Müller',0,10001,0,NULL,'30 Tage netto','Zahlbar innerhalb von 30 Tagen ohne Abzug',NULL,30,0,0.0,1,0.0,0.0,978,0,NULL,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,'Frau','König Petra','König','Petra','Betriebswirtin (VWA)',NULL,'Freiburger Allee',NULL,'Berlin','12345',NULL,'030/123466',NULL,NULL,NULL,'Nachfolgend bieten wir Ihnen wie folgt an:',NULL,'2014-09-25 00:00:00.000',NULL,1998.4,2378.1,0.0,0.0,379.7,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,2378.1,0.0,2378.1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,11,0,0,0,0,0,'2014-10-01 19:27:30.000','U0','2014-10-01 19:38:05.407','U0',0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,0,NULL,0,0.0,NULL,NULL,0,0,0,'2014-09-27 00:00:00.000',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0.0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,2,0,0,0,'1900-04-08 00:00:00.000',NULL,0,NULL,0,0,NULL,NULL,988.0,0,NULL,0,0,0.0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Is this query complete? Please post the entire query as well as the create table statements for the table(s) involved

Comment: This is probably extremely slow,replace all those subqueries with CASE WHEN..THEN to minimize the trips to the db

Comment: @Tom - The Query is complete. I've added additional infos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use a query with a single `SELECT` like this one:

```
SELECT CAST(10001 AS varchar)) AS KdNr
    , CAST(2014 AS varchar)) AS LastYear
    , CAST(2015 AS varchar)) AS CurrentYear
    , LY1 = ROUND(SUM(
            CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung <> 4 
                AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=1 
                AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=2014 
            THEN Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt 
            ELSE 0 END
            - 
            CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung = 4 
                AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=1 
                AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=2014
            THEN Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt 
            ELSE 0 END
        ), 2)
... add LY2 to LY11 here
    , LY12 = ROUND(SUM(
            CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung <> 4 AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=12 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=2014 THEN Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt ELSE 0 END
            - CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung = 4 AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=12 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=2014 THEN Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt ELSE 0 END
        ), 2)
    , LY = ROUND(SUM(
            CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung <> 4 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=2014 THEN Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt ELSE 0 END
            - CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung = 4 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=2014 THEN Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt ELSE 0 END
        ), 2)
    , CY1 = ROUND(SUM(
            CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung <> 4 AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=1 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=2015 THEN Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt ELSE 0 END
            - CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung = 4 AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=1 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=2015 THEN Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt ELSE 0 END
        ), 2)
... add CY2 to CY11 here
    , CY12 = ROUND(SUM(
            CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung <> 4 AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=12 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=2015 THEN Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt ELSE 0 END
            - CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung = 4 AND MONTH(Datum_erfassung)=12 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=2015 THEN Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt ELSE 0 END
        ), 2)
    , CY = ROUND(SUM(
            CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung <> 4 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=2015 THEN Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt ELSE 0 END
            - CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung = 4 AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung)=2015 THEN Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt ELSE 0 END
        ), 2)
FROM FK_Auftrag 
WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3, 6, 25, 4) 
    AND bStatus_storniert=0 
    AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr 
    AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung) IN (2014, 2015)
```

You can replace 2014 and 2015 by parameters from your code.

You must copy/paste and edit missing month between 1 and 12.

This should work as well. It may not be as efficient (try it?) but it is more compact and easier to work with:

```
SELECT CAST(10001 AS varchar)) AS KdNr
    , CAST(2014 AS varchar)) AS LastYear
    , CAST(2015 AS varchar)) AS CurrentYear
    , PIV.[LY1], PIV.[LY2], PIV.[LY3], PIV.[LY4], PIV.[LY5], PIV.[LY6], PIV.[LY7], PIV.[LY8], PIV.[LY9], PIV.[LY10], PIV.[LY11], PIV.[LY12]
    , LY = PIV.[LY1] + PIV.[LY2] + PIV.[LY3] + PIV.[LY4] + PIV.[LY5] + PIV.[LY6] + PIV.[LY7] + PIV.[LY8] + PIV.[LY9] + PIV.[LY10] + PIV.[LY11] + PIV.[LY12]
    , PIV.[CY1], PIV.[CY2], PIV.[CY3], PIV.[CY4], PIV.[CY5], PIV.[CY6], PIV.[CY7], PIV.[CY8], PIV.[CY9], PIV.[CY10], PIV.[CY11], PIV.[CY12]
    , CY = PIV.[CY1] + PIV.[CY2] + PIV.[CY3] + PIV.[CY4] + PIV.[CY5] + PIV.[CY6] + PIV.[CY7] + PIV.[CY8] + PIV.[CY9] + PIV.[CY10] + PIV.[CY11] + PIV.[CY12]
FROM (
    SELECT y = CASE WHEN YEAR(Datum_erfassung) = 2014 THEN 'LY' ELSE 'CY' END + CAST(MONTH(Datum_erfassung) AS varchar(2))
        , v = CASE WHEN AuftragsKennung = 4 THEN -(Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt) ELSE Summen_gesamt-Summen_ust_gesamt END
    FROM FK_Auftrag 
    WHERE AuftragsKennung IN (3,6,25, 4) 
        AND bStatus_storniert=0 
        AND KundenNr LIKE KdNr 
        AND YEAR(Datum_erfassung) IN (2014, 2015) 
) d
PIVOT (
    SUM(v)
    FOR y IN([LY1], [LY2], [LY3], [LY4], [LY5], [LY6], [LY7], [LY8], [LY9], [LY10], [LY11], [LY12]
            , [CY1], [CY2], [CY3], [CY4], [CY5], [CY6], [CY7], [CY8], [CY9], [CY10], [CY11], [CY12]) 
) AS PIV
```